# What kind of object is returned by dns.lookup method?

Tags: node.js, dns

I understand that my question is certainly not specific to dns.lookup function but can someone explain to me the returned object ?

```
> dns.lookup("google.com",function(err, address, family){});
> { callback: { [Function: asyncCallback] immediately: true },
    family: 0,
    hostname: 'google.com',
    oncomplete: [Function: onlookup],
    domain: 
    { domain: null,
       _events: { error: [Function] },
       _maxListeners: undefined,
       members: [] } }
```

Comment: What version of node are you using?  The return value of that function has changed quite a bit between versions.

Comment: I'm using v0.12.7, last version before io.js merged back